# Como validar que el prompt que se ingresa es un STRING en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, validación, function, prompt

Hola buenos días/tardes/noches, soy nuevo en todo esto de JavaScript, se me ocurrió hacer una función donde si el User ingresa un string en un prompt le diga que pueda entrar, o si ingreso un numero no lo deje entrar.

```
let nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");

function saludar(nombre) {
  
    if (nombre === "string") {
        alert(`Hola ${nombre}, buenos dias`);
    } else {
        alert(` ${nombre} No es un nombre valido!`);
  }
}

saludar(nombre);
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por defecto, `prompt()` te va a devolver una cadena o `null` si el valor es vacío. Si quieres que solo contenga letras, probablemente debas usar una expresión regular.

Comment: Explica mejor que resultado o comportamiento tiene este código

Comment: @BetaM Lo que quiero hacer es que el programa solo deje ingresar nombres de usuarios de tipo STRING, y que si el usuario ingresa NUMBER lo rechaze.

Comment: @triby Como seria eso?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar una expresion regular que verifique si se ingreso numeros en lugar de letras

```js
let nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");

function saludar(nombre) {
  let regex = /[0-9]+/; // esta expresion define que puede haber una o mas números.

    if(nombre == ''){
      return alert(`Debe agregar un nombre!`);
    }else if(!regex.test(nombre)){
        return alert(`Hola ${nombre}, buenos dias`);
    }else{
      return alert(` ${nombre} No es un nombre valido!`);
    }
}

saludar(nombre);
```

Comment: Esta respuesta me parece correcta. Yo sólo le agregaría una validación de caracteres especiales, pero ya es valor agregado.

Comment: Esa exprecion regular entonces que permite? Porque ingreso letras o numeros por separado y siempre me sale que no es un nombre valido

Comment: Si bien la funcionalidad esta bien, el `return` lo veo innecesario a menos que quieras que no se ejecute mas codigo despues de la `condicion`

Answer (score 0):

Quiero dar mi aporte referenciando una pregunta parecida a esta

```js
let nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");

function saludar(nombre) {
  var regex = new RegExp('^[A-Z]+$', 'i');
  
  if ( regex.test(nombre) ) {
    alert(`Hola ${nombre}, buenos dias`);
  }else {
    alert('Ingrese un nombre valido')
  }
}

saludar(nombre);
```

**Referencia**

- [Validar-solo-letras-js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230177/validar-solo-letras-en-javascript)

Comment: En estos casos Juan Rivera lo adecuado es marcarla como duplicada entonces

Comment: @BetaM la pongo como respuesta porque en otras ocaciones preguntas parecidas las marque como duplicadas y siempre me las rechazaban, ahora, aqui se esta utilizando `promt` y en el otra solamente la `exprecion-regular`. Entonces seria duplicada?

Comment: Considero que si, pero podemos ver que dice la comunidad entonces esperemos